# @Content.Script does not exsit in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am using razor asp.net mvc4 and I am getting an error in the view just in this block:

```
@section scripts
{
    @Content.Script("/Component/ComponentGrid.js", Url)
}
```

My script is in: \Scripts\Component\ComponentGrid.js

Compiler output: CS0103: The name 'Content' does not exist in the current context

This is my web.config in the view:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 5):

`@Content.Script` is not a standard method built-in ASP.NET MVC 4 or Razor 2. If you are using some third party components, ensure you have read their documentation and added the proper namespace in order to bring them in scope or fully qualify it:

```
@SomeNamespace.Content.Script("/Component/ComponentGrid.js", Url)
```

Comment: The only third-party i am using is jqGrid but i am not sure if it is...  I am adapting below http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/594150/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-4-jqGrid-In?msg=4668708#xx4668708xx to my mvc project. If i put mouse on @Content it says: class ASP.Content from the project in the link above¿?

Comment: ok, solved, some code was missed form the project in the link above provided... it was a razor file.very sorry...